# Networkx: Plot a subgraph similar to subcomponent in igraph R

Tags: python, r, pandas, networkx, subcomponent

I'm trying to plot a networkx graph on Python. Instead of plotting all nodes and edges, I'd like to filter out nodes which has link to a user given node. I think this is similar to subcomponent in iGraph in R. 
For example, in the below code, my dataframe has a node 4429. I'd like to plot nodes and edges that are connected directly or indirectly to 4429.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab

G = nx.DiGraph()

g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(dataframe, 'Source', 'Target', ['Freq'])
nx.draw_networkx(g)
plt.xticks([], [])
plt.yticks([], [])
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(15, 15)

plt.show()
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [this](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_component_subgraphs.html) what you are looking for?

Edit: not sure why this is downvoted but I think this is literally the answer. Here is an example:

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots
G = nx.path_graph(4)
G.add_edge(5,6)

fig, ax = subplots(2)
for axi, sub in zip(ax, nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)):
    nx.draw(sub, ax = axi)
```

[image]

edit 2: for only the subnet connected to a node use this:

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots
G = nx.path_graph(4)
G.add_edge(5,6)

fig, ax = subplots()
subnet = nx.node_connected_component(G, 0)
nx.draw(G.subgraph(subnet), ax = ax, with_labels = True)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The OP wants to plot a particular subgraph.

Comment: Ah gotcha, answer is edited

Comment: Could you edit your answer to be shorter?   There's a lot to go through before getting to the part that answers the question.

Comment: The second answer works perfectly.. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

A fast solution could be filtering the dataframe:

```
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(dataframe.loc[(dataframe["Source"] == id) | (dataframe["Target"] == id)])
```

If you know the maximum degree you can use `single_source_dijkstra_path_length`

```
nx.single_source_dijkstra_path_length(G=graph,
                                      Source=id,
                                      cutoff=cutoff)
```

Comment: Doing this would only give the nodes which are in direct contact with given id. But I'd like to find all nodes that might have the parent as id. Example: Id is 41 so 40-41 is one pair. But 39-40 can be another pair where 39 has indirect connection with 41 since 40 is connected with 41. So 39-40-41 should be plotted.

Comment: Even if there are more than 2 jumps?

Comment: Yeah. The jumps can be any number. It can just one node in direct contact with given target node. Or it can be a long chain of nodes, which ultimately end at Target or start from Target.

Answer (score 0):

Among all connected components, find the one that contains the node in question, and plot it.

```
subs = nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)
seed = 4429
g = [sg for sg in subs if seed in sg][0]
nx.draw_networkx(g)
```

Comment: See my answer (2nd edit)

Comment: it would be better to use `nx.node_connected_component` (see the second part of @GlobalTraveler's answer)